# Best design to deal with subclasses of a database?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a class called a `Plane`.

```
class Plane {
   private int _planeId;      

   public int getModel() { }

   public int getNumberOfPassengers() {}
}
```

And I another class called PlaneService which depends on plane and adds some logic to it,

```
class PlaneService  {
   private Plane _plane;

   public PlaneService(Plane _plane) {
        this._plane = _plane;
   }

   public void validdatePlane(int planeId) {
       fetch plane from planeId from db.
       if ( plane.getNumberOfPassengers() is in range of {100 to 300} )
          plane is valid.
   }
}
```

But now a new requirement comes in: plane must be extended to support fighter jets. So new design looks like this:

```
   class Plane {
       private int _planeId;      

       public int getModel() { }
    }

    class PassengerPlane extends Plane {
       public int getNumberOfPassengers() {}
    }

    class FigherJet extends Plane {
      public boolean isCommissioned() {} 
   }
```

My question is how can I best design 'PlaneSvc'in OOP way ? Is there a good design pattern ?

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
class PlaneService  {
       private Plane _plane;

       public PlaneService(Plane _plane) {
            this._plane = _plane;
       }

       public void validdatePlane(int planeId) {
           fetch CommercialPlane from planeId from db.
           if (commericialPlaneObject != null) {
              if ( plane.getNumberOfPassengers() is in range of {100 to 300} )
                 plane is valid.
           } 
           fetch FighterPlaneObject from planeId from db.
            if (FighterPlaneObject != null) {
                if (fighterplane.isCommissioned()) {
                   return validPlane;
                } 
            }
       }
    }
```

I am sure there is some design pattern to deal with such a case. I need to understand a cleaner approach to if-else here.

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is the strategy pattern and you can find it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm).

I dont thing you should pass planeId to the method because you have attached an plane to the PlaneService in the constructor which means that no service without a plane, i also assume that plane has the planeId in it.

If you want the implementation not to be bound at compile time you should use [bridge](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/bridge_pattern.htm) pattern. More or less is the same but you use it for structural purpuses and you pass the delegator not in the constructor but with a setter method.

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): [...] ***Provide context for links*** - *Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there.* ***Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.*** [...]

Comment: How to answer a question first and then edit, this is a better guide i guess!

Answer (score 2):

You could define a validate method in the plane class, for example:

```
class Plane {
       private int _planeId;    
       public boolean validate(){
            return false;
       }
       public int getModel() { }
    }
```

and then in the child classes, you could override the behavior of the validate method:

```
class FigherJet extends Plane {
      public boolean isCommissioned() {}

     @Override
     public boolean validate() {
        return isComissioned();
    }
}

class PassengerPlane extends Plane {
   public int getNumberOfPassengers() {}
   @Override
   public boolean validate(){
        //if plane.getNumberOfPassengers() is 100 to 300, return true, else return false
   }
}
```

And then your plane service can call the `validate()` method on any of the child objects:

```
  public boolean validatePlane(int planeId) {
       //fetch passenger plane from planeId from db.
       if (passengerPlane != null) {
          return passengerPlane.validate();
       } 
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) patter for this case as well.

```
    class Plane {
       private int _planeId;      

       public int getModel() { }

       abstract boolean validateWith(PlaneValidator validator);
    }

    class PassengerPlane extends Plane {
       public int getNumberOfPassengers() {}

       boolean validateWith(PlaneValidator validator) {
         return validator.validate(this);
       }
    }

    class FigherJet extends Plane {
      public boolean isCommissioned() {} 

      boolean validateWith(PlaneValidator validator) {
        return validator.validate(this);
      }
    }

    class PlaneService implements PlaneValidator {
      ...
      boolean validatePlane(int planeId) {
        //fetch Plane object from db
        return plane.validateWith(this);
      }

      //Methods implemented from PlaneValidator
      @Override
      boolean validate(FighterJet plane) {
        return plane.isCommissioned();
      }

      @Override
      boolean validate(PassengerPlane plane) {
        return plane.getNumberOfPassengers() in range(100, 300);
      }
    }
```

In this way, you can easily extend your system with new types, all thing you need to do is override `validateWith(PlaneValidator)` method in derived type and add appropriate method to `PlaneValidator` and describe its behavior in implemented method. I don't know is it pattern applicable to your system, but for me looks it could be.